# Right shift content of int array to num

Tags: java, arrays

I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 9, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i++) {
        swapNum(array[i], array[i+2]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

    public static void swapNum(int a, int b){

        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;

    }
```

But found that it is not swapping values. Then I took help from here
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86016/left-shifting-an-array-of-ints

```
public void anotherTry() {
    int nums [] = {4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8};

    for (int i = 0, start = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            start = nums[i];
        if (i == (nums.length - 1)) {
            nums[i] = start;
            break;
        }
        nums[i+2] = nums[i];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

Its gives array out of bound of exception.

1. Where I am wrong?
2. Role of `start` variable. If `start` always will be equal to `nums[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't swap values like that in Java. However, since you are using an array and want to swap values within the array, you can rewrite your `swap` method to work with indexes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 9, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i++) {
        swapNum(array, i, i+2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
public static void swapNum(int[] values, int i, int j){

    int tmp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[j];
    values[j] = tmp;

}
```

Comment: @paul - Well, yes, that's the logic you programmed into the main loop. I just showed how to swap values at two locations, which I thought was the point of this question. If you're now having problems figuring out how to get the overall logic right, you should perhaps post a separate question about that, explaining what you are trying accomplish, what you've tried, and what's going wrong (including expected and actual outputs).

Comment: Second code that I showed doesnt have the swap method. As per question there are 3 problems as we read `1. Question title: Right shift ....` `2. whats the role of start var...` `3. Where I am wrong...`

Comment: @paul - Sorry, but the way I read your post is that the second code sample was a failed attempt to fix the problem that your original `swap()` method wasn't doing anything. You can use your original logic by running through the array in reverse order (varying `i` from `array.length-1` down to `2`) and swapping `i` and `i-2` (instead of `i` and `i+2`). Basically, just do a mirror image of the current logic.